# 'StorageMetadata' has no member 'downloadURL'

Tags: ios, swift

So, I've gotten 2 more errors in my code which I've tried to solve for a while for my school project, but since I'm not used to programming in swift I haven't been able to solve it (I've taken code from a youtube tutorial). The first one is "Value of 'StorageMetaData' has no member 'downloadURL' (inside the func uploadImg). Then the other erros is "use of unresolved identifier 'imagePicker' (at the end of @IBAction func selectedImgPicker".
Here's my code:

```swift
class SignUpVC: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var userImagePicker: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var signUpBtn: UIButton!

    var userUid: String!
    var emailField: String!
    var passwordField: String!
    var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!
    var imageSelected = false
    var username: String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imagePicker.delegate = self as? UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate
        imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if let _ = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "uid"){
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "Message", sender: nil)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]){
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage{
            userImagePicker.image = image
            imageSelected = true
        } else {
            print("image wasnt selected")
        }
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func setUser(img: String){
        let userData = ["username": username!, "userImg": img]

        KeychainWrapper.standard.set(userUid, forKey: "uid")

        let location = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userUid)
        location.setValue(userData)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func uploadImg(){
        if usernameField.text == nil {
            signUpBtn.isEnabled = false
        } else {
            username = usernameField.text
            signUpBtn.isEnabled = true
        }
        guard let img = userImagePicker.image, imageSelected == true else{
            print("image needs to be selected")
            return
        }
        if let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.2){
            let imgUid = NSUUID().uuidString
            let metadata = StorageMetadata()
            metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"
            Storage.storage().reference().putData(imgData, metadata: metadata){
                (metadata, error) in

                if error != nil{
                    print("did not upload image")
                }else{
                    print("uploaded")

                    let downloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString

                    if let url = downloadURL{
                        self.setUser(img: url)
                    }
                }
                }
            }
        }

    @IBAction func createAccount(_ sender: AnyObject){
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailField, password: passwordField, completion: {
            (user, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Cant create user")
            } else {
                if let user = user {
                    self.userUid = user.user.uid
                }
            }
            self.uploadImg()
        })
    }

    @IBAction func selectedImgPicker (_ sender: AnyObject){
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func cancel (_ sender: AnyObject){
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Next problem, you’re trying to set delegate of implicitly unwrapped optional which is `nil`. Rather assign delegate after you assign `imagePicker` property

Comment: Maybe you can find an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=StorageMetadata%27+has+no+member+%27downloadURL%27)